# voyager linux cpu and time display customize

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, time, cpu

I want to move time and cpu display of voyager linux(xubuntu fork).
in default setting, it is at left. I want to move it to right top.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solved myself
voyager uses conky

for select thema
any where desktop > right click > voyager box > Conkey control

to open config file
cd
cd .conkey